# How to get specific information from the website and display it in a box?

Tags: url, autoit

I am quite newbie on AutoIT, I've done alot of things already.

But I can't find out the way to read specific information from the website that is between `div` or something. If thats not possible, maybe there is a way to read a raw `*.txt(or php)` file from the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code example for your URL:

```
#include <IE.au3>

$oIE = _IECreate("http://test.com/check.php")
$divs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "div")

For $div In $divs
    If $div.className == "content-container" Then
        MsgBox(0, "Bestimmter Inhalt", $div.innerText)
    EndIf
Next

_IEQuit($oIE)
```

You asked for the "raw Text", which is best read with the attribute `innerText`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

This example basically opens a new IE window with the given URL. Then it extracts all the `div`-Elements and iterates through them in a loop. Once the `className` is `"content-container"` the content of this element is displayed in a message box. Finally the IE window is closed again.

You could add the parameters `, 0, 0` to the `_IECreate()` function to hide the browser window in the end.

Instead of searching for a specific `<div>`-Element as shown here you could just use the following two lines...

```
$body = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "body", 0)
MsgBox(0, "Komplette Webseite", $body.innerText)
```